# Como fazer o teste unitário do Spring Boot inserir os dados no Banco?

Tags: java, spring-boot, testes-de-unidade, junit

Criei um sistema simples que está funcionando perfeitamente, porém estou precisando implementar um teste unitário no Spring Boot, o que acontece que ao efetuar o teste ou não consigo inserir os dados no banco ou gera erro;

Eu tentei dessa forma, não gerou erro, mas também não conseguiu salvar no banco;

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import com.projeto.subium.api.model.Project;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class SubiumApplicationTests {



    @Test
    public void testAdicionarEmployee() throws Exception {
        Project project1 = new Project();
        String nome1 = new String("Google");
        project1.setName(nome1);


    }
}
```

Depois tentei dessa forma, mas gerou erro, eu atualizei o código;

```
   import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import com.projeto.subium.api.service.ProjectService;
import com.projeto.subium.api.model.Project;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class SubiumApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private ProjectService projectService;

    @Test
    public void testAdicionarEmployee(){
        Project project1 = new Project("Google");
        this.projectService.salvar(project1);
    }
}
```

**O que preciso é gerar o teste de tal forma que ele possa conseguir salvar os dados no banco.**

Essa é a mensagem de erro na IDE;

```
2018-09-19 11:05:49.602 ERROR 1564 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@1a38c59b] to prepare test instance [com.projeto.subium.api.SubiumApplicationTests@36068727]

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.projeto.subium.api.SubiumApplicationTests': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'projectService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.projeto.subium.api.service.ProjectService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87) ~[spring-beans-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) ~[spring-beans-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1269) ~[spring-beans-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:384) ~[spring-beans-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118) ~[spring-test-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83) ~[spring-test-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:44) ~[spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-1.5.16.RELEASE.jar:1.5.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230) ~[spring-test-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228) [spring-test-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287) [spring-test-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) [spring-test-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247) [spring-test-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94) [spring-test-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191) [spring-test-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206) [.cp/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.projeto.subium.api.service.ProjectService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1491) ~[spring-beans-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1102) ~[spring-beans-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1064) ~[spring-beans-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585) ~[spring-beans-4.3.19.RELEASE.jar:4.3.19.RELEASE]
    ... 29 common frames omitted

2018-09-19 11:05:49.627  INFO 1564 --- [       Thread-3] o.s.w.c.s.GenericWebApplicationContext   : Closing org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@4229bb3f: startup date [Wed Sep 19 11:05:45 GFT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-09-19 11:05:49.646  INFO 1564 --- [       Thread-3] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-09-19 11:05:49.647  INFO 1564 --- [       Thread-3] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000227: Running hbm2ddl schema export
Hibernate: drop table employee if exists
Hibernate: drop table employeeproject if exists
Hibernate: drop table project if exists
2018-09-19 11:05:49.704  INFO 1564 --- [       Thread-3] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000230: Schema export complete
```

Comment: Sua primeira forma não salvou no banco porque você só seta o nome, não chama método algum de salvamento. Na segunda forma, você chama, mas é preciso saber o erro que dá. Poderia editar sua pergunta e incluir a stacktrace desse erro?

Comment: @StatelessDev eu reeditei a pergunta e coloquei a imagem do erro, poderia dar uma olhada por favor.

Comment: eu fiz uma atualização em toda a postagem, então gostaria que pudesse ler do inicio, por favor.

Comment: Esse teste não irá funcionar, já que existe uma dependência do container estar rodando para realizar transações ao banco de dados, se ele rodar você não consegue utilizar os métodos do service também, por causa da injeção. Eu aconselharia a criar um teste unitário de maneira que teste, somente o método salvar(), coisas como regras de negócio por exemplo, o save propriamente dito, você pode criar um mock para retornar algo, simulando uma transação com o banco de dados.

Answer (score 0):

Eu usei @SpringBootTest ao invés do @DataJpaTest e deu certo ! Talvez esse seja o problema.